# Center larger div to smaller div?

Tags: css

I would like to know how I can align two divs.
The first div is smaller than the second one and I want to center the second one to the first one (like if you would do in Photoshop where the focal point of an object gets aligned to the focal point of the other object so that they are on one level)

Just a quick sketch

[image]

I hope you understand what I mean :D

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/  That has a lot of methods.  Check them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `display:inline-block` (as opposed to `float:left`), then you can use `vertical-align:middle` to vertically align the two elements by their middle line.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 That is unsustainable, especially if the elements change size for any reason.

Comment: I am just mentioning in case `inline-block` isn't supported (which shouldn't happen).

Comment: I thought vertical-align only worked when the element is display:table-cell and the parent is display:table  (or they actually are, in fact, tables.)

Comment: `vertical-align` works on all elements, it just doesn't seem to have any effect most of the time. It has a noticeable effect on inline and inline-block elements that have a different height from the rest of the line.